# Jquery carouFredSel from array

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

I am using the caroufredsel and add the carousel's elements via html:

```
<ul>
  <li> element 1 </li>
  <li> element 2 </li>
  <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

What I wanted to do now ist not to hardcode the elements in html, instead I want the caroufredsel read the items from an javascript array.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop through the array and append the variable to the `ul`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var testArr = ["element 1","element 2","element 3","element 4"];
    var listItem ="";
    $.each(testArr, function(i, val) {
         listItem += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
    });

    $('#myUL').html(listItem);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Q6wZ/)